# Not able to get the data from the JSON in OpenSocial App!

Tags: java, opensocial, json

I have follwing JSON: 
{"mykey":[{name:"Jak",interests:"movies"}]}

and following opensocial app code:

```
  <script type="text/os-template" require="mykey">                           
    <ul>
      <li repeat="${mykey}">
          <span>Offer id: ${Cur.name}</span>              
          <span>Offer: ${Cur.interests}</span>          
      </li>
    </ul>
 </script>
```

but the App is not able to get the data from the JSON? Not able to find out the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue, actually the fix is as follows:

  Offer id: ${Cur.key.name}
  Offer: ${Cur.key.interests}